# I'll call it a week

Tags: idioms

I work in a multi-national company and I've heared this sentence a lot from non-native speakers on Fridays.

> I'll call it a week.

I'm not a native speaker, but to my ears it's only natural to say:

> I'll call it a day.

Which one is right?

Do you use another sentence to finish your week?

Comment: Possibly related: [Can I say “Call it a project” similar to “Call it a day”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/88366/can-i-say-call-it-a-project-similar-to-call-it-a-day)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Let's call it a day" is an idiom, even a cliché.  Meaning "Let us decide to end work now".

It is productive enough that "Call it a week" is a natural development. People normally have a break from work at the weekend, analogous to the break from work overnight. It and has plenty of [examples on the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22call%20it%20a%20week.%22&oq=%22call%20it%20a%20week.%22). It would be less natural to say "Call it a month" because normally people don't have a break from work at the end of the month.

You don't need any sentence to end the day or the week.  If you say the same thing everyday it would sound boring.  There are so many things you could say  "I'm off now", "Have a great weekend, everyone", "See you all on Monday" and so on.

Comment: When we closed our accounts on March 31, someone in my office actually said 'we'll call it a year'. UK finance years run 1 April to 31 March.